# Vertical scrollbar is not working It become in active

Tags: javascript, html, css

The vertical scroll bar has become inactive. The strange thing about this code is that it is running fine from where I copied it but for me, the scrollbar is there but it is not clickable(it is more like transparent). I can move it with the arrow keys but not with the mouse. Why is this so?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a54d2cbf95.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Back To Top</title>
</head>


<style>
    * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y:  auto;
}

section {
  height:75vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.section1 {
  background: #f0932b;
}

.section2 {
  background: #eb4d4b;
}

.section3 {
  background: #7ed6df;
}

.section4 {
  background: #22a6b3;
}

.to-top {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 16px;
  right:32px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:32px;
  color:#1f1f1f;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.to-top.active {
  bottom:32px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity:1;
}
</style>

<body>

  <section class="section1">Section 1</section>
  <section class="section2">Section 2</section>
  <section class="section3">Section 3</section>
  <section class="section4">Section 4</section>

  <a href="#" class="to-top">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </a>

  <script >
      const toTop = document.querySelector(".to-top");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
    toTop.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    toTop.classList.remove("active");
  }
})
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To make the scrollbar active is my main problem. I am actually trying to change the style of the scroll bar

I'll be very grateful if you fix my code. All I want is to be able to scroll with my mouse.

I tried a couple of things but it didn't help.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to fixed current code try to create a new scroll  bar..scroll bar code is given below ...

**just copy past it customize it and enjoy**

```css
/****************    scroll bar      *******************/



  ::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 12px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
 border-radius: 10px;
 /* -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3); */
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(160deg, rgb(68, 67, 67),rgb(129, 127, 127), rgb(68, 67, 67));
  
}


/****************    /scroll bar      ********************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `overflow-y: auto;` 
It should be **scroll** or **visible**

Answer (score 0):

**The arrow icon problem is with your fontawesome kit. You can look into that otherwise you can use fontawesome cdn. I added some css for scrollbar now It will work perfectly fine.**

```js
const toTop = document.querySelector(".to-top");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
    toTop.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    toTop.classList.remove("active");
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y:  auto;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

section {
  height:75vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
}

.section1 {
  background: #f0932b;
}

.section2 {
  background: #eb4d4b;
}

.section3 {
  background: #7ed6df;
}

.section4 {
  background: #22a6b3;
}

.to-top {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 16px;
  right:32px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size:32px;
  color:#1f1f1f;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.to-top.active {
  bottom:32px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="section1">Section 1</section>
  <section class="section2">Section 2</section>
  <section class="section3">Section 3</section>
  <section class="section4">Section 4</section>

  <a href="#" class="to-top">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```